# Boost Mountain Lion linking

Tags: c++, boost, linker, osx-mountain-lion

I'm triing to link to boost 1.50 on Mountain Lion with Xcode V 4.4
I'm using gcc 4.7, so no Xcode stuff should be involved. 
Every time I'm triing to link it gives me this:

```
/usr/local/bin/g++  -o bin/parse -Lbin `root-config --ldflags`    build/Bcf.o build/Bmf.o build/Boc.o build/EasyBMP.o build/Fei4.o build/Options.o build/RxChannel.o build/TxChannel.o -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem  -lboc `root-config --libs` build/parse.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "start", referenced from:
     -u command line option
     (maybe you meant: boost::property_tree::string_path<std::basic_string<char,    std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::property_tree::id_translator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::cstart() const, boost::progress_display::restart(unsigned long) , boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::definition<boost::spirit::classic::scanner<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies<boost::spirit::classic::skip_parser_iteration_policy<boost::spirit::classic::alternative<boost::spirit::classic::alternative<boost::spirit::classic::space_parser, boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser<boost::spirit::classic::strlit<char const*>, boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star<boost::spirit::classic::anychar_parser>, boost::spirit::classic::alternative<boost::spirit::classic::eol_parser, boost::spirit::classic::end_parser>, boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category, boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme> >, boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser<boost::spirit::classic::strlit<char const*>, boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star<boost::spirit::classic::anychar_parser>, boost::spirit::classic::strlit<char const*>, boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category, boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme> >, boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy, boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> > >::start() const )
  "boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem::exists(boost::filesystem::path const&) in Bcf.o
  "boost::filesystem::detail::file_size(boost::filesystem::path const&,boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem::file_size(boost::filesystem::path const&) in Bcf.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Boost was build after the Update and it worked before

I tried building it using macports or homebrew, but this breaks everything...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the recipe I used to build Boost on 10.8 (with the latest Xcode from the App Store) that definitely works:

1. Download http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.50.0/boost_1_50_0.tar.bz2/download
2. `tar jxvf boost_1_50_0.tar.bz2 && cd "boost_1_50_0/"`
3. `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/opt/boost-1.50`
4. (as admin user) `sudo ./b2 install`
5. `sudo ln -snf boost-1.50 /opt/boost`

Comment: Are you sure about step 5 ? This seems to contradict step 3. My boost files end up in boost_1_50_0/boost and bootstrap.sh creates /opt/boost-1.50.

Comment: The last step is not critical, it just gives me a way to run things with a version-free path.  Whenever I compile new versions of packages, I update these kinds of links to point to the latest version.